# What's the meaning of "twice continuously differentiable"?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

The picture is from *Complex Analysis* by Stein.

What's the meaning of "twice continuously differentiable"?

Answer (score 8):

It means that the functions $\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$, $\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}$, and $\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}$ exist and are continuous.

Comment: Suppose $U$ is an open set of $R^m$ and $f:U\to \Bbb R^n$ is differentiable, then $f'(x)\in L(\Bbb R^m,\Bbb R^n)$ for $x\in U$, but how to define $f''(x)$?

Comment: I thought that you were talking about real functions. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Twice continuously differentiable means the second derivative exists and is continuous.